# Xcode 15: iOS simulators set to Auotmatic never show as run target, only when set to Always. Why?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When set to always, it will show up but when set to automatic, it never shows up.

[image: iPhone 14 / iOS 17 Simulator]

My project settings include iPhone and deployment target is iOS 15 but also when setting it to iOS 17 it won't show up.

[image: Project settings including iPhone & iPad, Deployment Target iOS 15]

I even downloaded the iOS 15 simulator and made an iPhone 12 target with iOS 15, that won't show up either.

[image: iPhone 12 / iOS 15 Simulator]

If I select always, it will show up and then I can also run the app in the simulator, also with deployment target iOS 15 on an iOS 17 simulator, no problem.

So why won't those simulators show up as target when set to automatic? What am I doing wrong? Does automatic work at all? Everywhere I search online for this question the answer is "Set to always" but that's not a real answer, that's a brute force work around.

There must be a reason why they don't show up when automatic is selected and I don't know how to debug this issue.